# Decide if a list has an even number of elements without counting the number of elements

Tags: function, haskell, boolean

> Implement the `isLengthEven :: [a] -> Bool` function that decides if a list contains an even number of elements. In this exercise, using the `length` function or any other function that returns the number of elements of a list is prohibited. Hint: All we have to check is whether we can walk the entirety of the list through two by two or does the function miss an item at the very end.

> For example: `isLengthEven "Apple" == True`, `isLengthEven "Even" == True`, `isLengthEven [] == False`

So far, I tried pattern matching and recursion, which is in my opinion the optimal way of doing this exercise. My code is as follows:

```
isLengthEven :: [a] -> Bool
isLengthEven [] = False
isLengthEven (x:[]) = False
isLengthEven (x:(y:[])) = True
isLengthEven (x:(y:(z:[]))) = False
isLengthEven (x:(y:(z:(q:[])))) = True
isLengthEven (x:xs) = isLengthEven (xs)
```

This returns the correct values up until I insert the fifth element into the list. It returns `True` for any number of elements above or equal to 5. I suppose there's a problem with the recursion part.

Comment: Your recursive case is wrong. And you don't need nearly that many base cases.

Comment: Also, one of your base cases is wrong.

Comment: You make too many base cases, and either `[]` should map on `True`, not `False`, since an empty list has length `0` which is even.

Comment: How would a correct recursive case look like and which base case is the unneeded one?

Comment: @AWheelbarrow: `(x:(y:[]))`, `(x:(y:(z:[])))`, and `(x:(y:(z:(q:[]))))` are not necessary.

Comment: the pattern `(x:(y:(z:(q:[]))))` is the same as the pattern `[x,y,z,q]`, just like with the values.

Comment: The problem statement includes `isLengthEven [] == False` and `isLengthEven "Apple" == True`. Are you (or your instructor) really sure those are sensible outputs? They certainly don't match the obvious specification of `isLengthEvenSpec = even . length`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need only two base cases here:

1. an *empty* list, which has as length `0` and thus should return `True`; and
2. a *singleton* list which contains one element and thus has an odd length.

The recursive cases each time move two steps forward in the list, so:

```
isLengthEven :: [a] -> Bool
isLengthEven [] = True
isLengthEven [x] = False
isLengthEven (_:_:xs) = isLengthEven xs
```

Often one defines two functions: `isLengthEven` and `isLengthOdd` and thus these functions each time call each other recursively with:

```
isLengthEven :: [a] -> Bool
isLengthEven [] = True
isLengthEven (_:xs) = isLengthOdd xs

isLengthOdd :: [a] -> Bool
isLengthOdd [] = False
isLengthOdd (_:xs) = isLengthEven xs
```

Answer (score 2):

### A single-stepping solution

Note that the excellent [answer by Willem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69605814/11282404) is already an optimized one.

If you prefer a straight unoptimized version and choose to disregard the hint, you can do with just the first and last clauses of your initial code. Like this:

```
-- warning: the following is incorrect, needs changes:
isLengthEven :: [a] -> Bool
isLengthEven [] = False
isLengthEven (x:xs) = isLengthEven (xs)
```

Both clauses are incorrect, but it is easy to fix them:

```
isLengthEven :: [a] -> Bool
isLengthEven [] = True
isLengthEven (x:xs) = not (isLengthEven xs)
```

and taken together, these two clauses cover all possible situations.

**Addendum:**

As is, this function uses a lot of stack space for long inputs. This can be fixed thru the common *accumulator-as-argument* trick. Here:

```
isLengthEven :: [a] -> Bool
isLengthEven xs = go True xs  where
    go b   []    =  b
    go b (x:xs)  =  go (not b) xs
```

where the `go` auxiliary stepping function is tail-recursive.

On my machine, performance of this single step solution (with that last change included) gets very close to the “two by two” solution advocated in the question text.

Both methods are getting about two thirds of the performance of the straightforward but prohibited `(even (length xs))` solution.

Comment: wouldn't it be more "optimized" if it had `isLengthEven (_:_:_:_:xs) = isLengthEven xs` on top, or even `isLengthEven (_:_:_:_:_:_:_:_:xs) = isLengthEven xs` on top of that?

Comment: @WillNess, I don't think so. I'd try ``isLengthEven xs = foldl' (\acc _ -> acc `xor` 1) 0 xs == (0 :: Int)``. That will fuse nicely, and should avoid unnecessary conditional branches.

Comment: @dfeuer interesting, thanks. your version would in effect do the indeterminate amount of the `_:`s of mine, flipping a bit in an accumulator as it goes. the last version in this answer "should" probably do the same. :)

Comment: @WillNess - FWIW on my PC, I do not get any significant performance changes when I change the step, whether 1, 2, or 4 list items. GHC v8.8.4 -O2. So it seems that pattern matching dominates function call overhead. And the obvious solution `even . length` is about 45% faster than these manual recursion versions. Library wins.

Comment: @jpmarinier, how are you testing? The manual versions will be bad if fusion would be possible with `length` or `foldl'`.